# How do I make <div> not cover images in HTML?

Tags: html, css, background, clipping

I used <div> to make a color changing background, but the background covers the image I have. How can I make the <div> stay in the background?
(Btw I know in my code there's 2 sections for color but deleting either of them makes the colors not work.) Here's what it looks like when run: https://the-hampsterdog-dance.glitch.me/
thanks in advance.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>DANCE THE NIGHT AWAY</title>  
      
      <img
        src="https://cdn.glitch.global/12de095f-ec41-45e3-a169-09c23630e626/tbag.gif?v=1648828203809"
        width="140"
        height="100"
        alt="DANCE THE NIGHT AWAY"
      />
     
      <div id="dog"></div>
      <style>
        

        @-webkit-keyframes bg-animation {
          15% {
            background-color: yellow;
          }
          30% {
            background-color: green;
          }
          45% {
            background-color: blue;
          }
          60% {
            background-color: purple;
          }
      
    animation: change 10s infinite;
      }
      @-webkit-keyframes change{
        25%{background-color: blue;}
        50%{background-color: green;}
        75%{background-color: purple;}        
      }
      #dog {
    position:absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    -webkit-animation: change 10s infinite;
}
    </style>
    </body>
  </head>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could either move the dog image inside `<div id="dog"></div>` or target the `body` rather than `#dog` for the background color animation. Both approaches will work.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    </head>
  <body>
    <title>DANCE THE NIGHT AWAY</title>  
      
      <img
        src="https://cdn.glitch.global/12de095f-ec41-45e3-a169-09c23630e626/tbag.gif?v=1648828203809"
        width="140"
        height="100"
        alt="DANCE THE NIGHT AWAY"
      />
     
      <div id="dog"></div>
      <style>
        

        @-webkit-keyframes bg-animation {
          15% {
            background-color: yellow;
          }
          30% {
            background-color: green;
          }
          45% {
            background-color: blue;
          }
          60% {
            background-color: purple;
          }
      
    animation: change 10s infinite;
      }
      @-webkit-keyframes change{
        25%{background-color: blue;}
        50%{background-color: green;}
        75%{background-color: purple;}        
      }
      body {
    position:absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 1000;
    -webkit-animation: change 10s infinite;
}
    </style>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Elements later inside the DOM ([Document Object Model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Introduction), essentially your HTML) usually are positioned on top of elements earlier. So the easiest solution is to switch the order of your `img` and `div`.

If this is not possible for whatever reason, you can change the layering in CSS using [`z-index`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp). The higher it’s value, the more the affected element gets on top. E.g. for `#dog`:

```
z-index: 99;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>DANCE THE NIGHT AWAY</title>
  <style>
    .foreground {
      z-index: 790909;
    }
    
    body{
          -webkit-animation: change 10s infinite;
    }
    
    @-webkit-keyframes bg-animation {
      15% {
        background-color: yellow;
      }
      30% {
        background-color: green;
      }
      45% {
        background-color: blue;
      }
      60% {
        background-color: purple;
      }
      animation: change 10s infinite;
    }
    
    @-webkit-keyframes change {
      25% {
        background-color: blue;
      }
      50% {
        background-color: green;
      }
      75% {
        background-color: purple;
      }
    }
    
    #dog {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      bottom: 0;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <img class="foreground" src="https://cdn.glitch.global/12de095f-ec41-45e3-a169-09c23630e626/tbag.gif?v=1648828203809" width="140" height="100" alt="DANCE THE NIGHT AWAY" />

  <div id="dog"></div>
</body>

</html>
```